# Merge by distance doesn't work-0 vertices removed message

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, loop

I'm using Blender 3.0 and whenever I try to merge vertices that are stacked right on top of each other, nothing happens. I get a message that says "0 vertices removed". Increasing the distance does nothing until it gets to a high number and starts merging the wrong vertices.

Help! Not a serious problem but it's important since I'm using lots of loop cuts and I want proper geometry.

Comment: The vertices all have to exist in the same object for a merge to work.  Is this the case in your sample file?  You can [edit] your question and paste in a screenshot to provide more info.

Comment: I figured it out. I need to be selecting all the vertices when I do the merge. I was trying to just select the object itself and merge because I thought it would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comments, you figured out your problem: it was that those vertices were not selected and you had to do this to merge them - but not necessarily:

As most Blender tools, the *Merge* tool shows an options box at the bottom left of the viewport, which you can open by clicking on it.

If you open it, there is an option *Unselected* which is disabled by default (so that you won't merge vertices accidentally which you didn't intend to merge). But when you enable it, all vertices within the *Merge Distance* will be merged, no matter if you selected them or not.

[image: merge options]